# problem in concept of javascript decorators

Tags: javascript, decorator, javascript-decorators

I am trying to learn decorators in javascript with the help of this article:
https://dev.to/logrocket/understanding-javascript-decorators-ba2.

My questions are:

1. How is it possible that in `Validator` function we can read arguments of `Multiply` function?
2. Why `Multiply` arguments are undefined before the `return function(...args)` inside the `Validator` function?

Here is the code:

```
let Multiply = (...args) => {
    return args.reduce((a, b) => a * b)
}

// validated integers
const Validator = (fn) => {
  return function(...args) {
    const validArgs = args.every(arg => Number.isInteger(arg));
    if (!validArgs) {
      throw new TypeError('Argument cannot be a non-integer');
    }
    return fn(...args);
  }
}

//decorated multiply function that only multiplies integers
MultiplyValidArgs = Validator(Multiply);
MultiplyValidArgs(6, 8, 2, 10);
```

Comment: -"function we can read arguments of Multiply function"_ we don't. The `Validator` passes the arguments of `MultiplyValidArgs` to `Multiply`

Comment: `Why Multiply arguments are undefined` Not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: `Validator` is a function that takes another function as argument. It returns a new function that calls the original function. Your question 1 does not apply because you are not passing the arguments to the original Multiply function but to the function returned by calling Validator on it.

Comment: Similarly, question 2 does not make sense. The original Multiply function is called here: `fn(...args)`. Your Validator code has access to the arguments passed to the modified function only inside the function it returns; before that the passed argument is the function that is to be decorated, not the numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validator creates and returns a new function (specified in the body `function(...args) { ...}`)

`...args` is the array of all parameters that will be given to that function when called. And it's this list of parameters that is inspected by the returned function, (not by the `Validator` function)
In the end the created function will call the initial function, given as a parameter to `Validator`, provided all parameters are numbers

So there are three functions involved:

1 the initial function `Multiply`

2 the `Validator` function, that can create a new function wrapping the initial function

3 the returned and function `MultiplyValidArgs` that you can use